# Adding pictures to textboxes

Tags: image, vba, ms-word

On worksheet there is a table in which I have put textboxes.

Now I want to add pictures to these textboxes.

> I use the code written below. But, although pictures get written, they are placed outside the textboxes. How can I make sure that they are placed within the boxes?

```
Sub AfbeeldingenLaden()
    Dim tekstvak As Shape
    Dim Bestandsnamen() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Bestandsnamen = AfbeeldingenKiezen()

    For Each tekstvak In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If tekstvak.Height > 20 Then
            tekstvak.Select

            If Bestandsnamen(i) <> "" Then
                  Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=Bestandsnamen(i), LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
            End If
            Set shp = Word.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
            shp.LockAspectRatio = False
            shp.Width = 208.35
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @Rohan: Please always also take a look at the tags. Improved it...

Answer (score 0):

It appears the the loop through the Shapes collection in the main body of the document is supposed to access text boxes and insert InlineShapes. The reason the pictures don't end up where you expect is because you don't provide anything for the `Range` parameter of `InlineShapes.AddPicture`. So Word is just guessing where to insert it...

In order to control where the picture is inserted, you need to specify the Range within the target text box. A TextBox has a TextFrame.TextRange property, where TextRange is the entire content of the textbox. From here, you can narrow it down to a specific paragraph or something similar. For example:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set rng = tekstvak.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(1).Range
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=Bestandsnamen(i), _
    LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=rng
```

Beyond that, it's difficult to be sure exactly what you expect of your code. I'm concerned that you're looping the Shapes collection for text boxes, but not checking the Shape.Type whether it's really `msoTextBox`.

Also, since tekstvak is a TextBox object I don't think you need `Set shp = Word.Selection.ShapeRange(1)` because you already have an object for the textbox. If that's the case, then you can do this, instead: `tekstvak.LockAspectRatio = False`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reaction. If I follow your instructions, I get a Type Mismatch error. But I'm sure that tekstvak is a textbox because if I do msgbox tekstvak.Type it gives me 17, which is a textbox.

```
For Each tekstvak In ActiveDocument.Shapes
   If tekstvak.Height > 20 Then
        tekstvak.Select

        If Bestandsnamen(i) <> "" Then
            Dim rng As Word.Range
            Set rgn = tekstvak.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(1).Range
            ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=Bestandsnamen(i), LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=rng
        End If
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next
```